# Google Chrome: Цифра в круглешке console.log

Tags: google-chrome, консоль

Что означает в console.log цифра 2 в круглешке?
SEDAN это результат данных перебора массива методом each [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что это значение было выведено N-раз подряд, в данном случае 2 раза. Для примера `(["dd", "dd", "dd", "dd"]).forEach( function(item){ console.log(item) })` выдаст уже 4 раза.